# Executing tasks in a loop getting Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the method bellow called by a web service

```
public void ExecuteTasks()
{
    var tf = new TasksFactory();
    var tasks = tf.GetPlaningTasks();
    foreach (var t in tasks)
    {
        var job = new ThreadStart(t.Execute);
        var thread = new Thread(job);
        thread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

This method acts like a cron and executes several jobs in tasks.

The problem is that sometimes I get thread abort exception and I don't know why.

The webservice is hosted on IIS and called by a Window Service each minute.

The exception is only thrown on production environment.

The number of tasks created is around 20.

The duration of each task can vary from 1s to 3min.

Comment: How are you hosting the web service, IIS worker process?

Comment: Inspect/watch the Exception to see, where it is thrown. Where do you catch that exception?

Comment: How many tasks are typically in `tasks` ?

Comment: [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) offers cautions about trying to do this and how to do it better. E.g. "The AppDomain your site runs in can go down for a number of reasons and take down your background task with it."